# Word as COM object has no attributes/ability to set attributes

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com

I'm sorry that this is quite alien to me, but I had a previously working script that functioned like the following:

```
$wd = new-object -comobject word.application
```

but when I print the COM object it has empty/blank values for all attributes.

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> $wd


Application                       : 
Creator                           : 
Parent                            : 
Name                              : 
Documents                         : 
Windows                           : 
ActiveDocument                    : 
ActiveWindow                      : 
Selection                         :
```

And it cannot set any or perform any functions

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> $wd.Visible = $true

Exception setting "Visible": "Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'. This 
operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading 
type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."
At line:1 char:1
+ $wd.Visible = $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

I tried browsing related questions but was unable to see if the mistakes are exactly identical. I've run all Windows updates and did a repair installation of Office. (Running Windows 10 and Office 2013)

Comment: Did you try a system restore?

Comment: @Theo the whole system? Why would/should that be necessary? It would be difficult to merge/sync work, and I don't know at what point it messed up.

Comment: Yes, but you can try `sfc /scannow` first. See [System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

Comment: Try searching your hard drive for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll, and copy the full path. Then try `Add-Type -Path <path to DLL>`, see if you continue to get the same error.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician interesting. Directory is `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c`. When I type `test-path -path <dir>` result is `True`. When I type `add-type -path <dir>`, result is `Add-Type : Cannot add type. The ".0__71E9BCE111E9429C" extension is not supported.`. Did Word sabbotage itself with a stupid naming convention that powershell can't parse?

Comment: You only entered the folder path, you need to include the file name as well.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I see. Well when I give the full path to the `.dll`, PS returns no value. But when I try to create a word comobject the same way, it still does not allow me to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Word/Excel/PPT COM Objects are acting wildly. Thus using these is not recommended for automation purposes by Microsoft itself (sorry but couldn't find the source). But whatever personally I use those all the time :).

*System Restore* or *closing and repoening the Powershell Session* actually fixes those problems for me.

Unfortunately I couldn't figured out a programmatic way to handle this  yet. So looking forward for further answers.  (+1)